# Block symmetric implies symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a matrix is block symmetric then does that imply it is symmetric? If this claim is true, how can I prove it?

Comment: What does block-symmetric mean? What if there is only one block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A \\ A & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, then $B$ is block symmetric but not symmetric.